# Cannot convert byte to string when getting data using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I fix this error which I get on this line of code:

```
Convert.ToByte(AdministrationCode);
```

I want to select Administration Code and store it in a textbox.

```
private void ShowAdministraionNo()
{
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCode.Text.Trim()))
        {
            var EmpCodeAsInt = Convert.ToInt32(txtCode.Text);

            using (var dbcontext = new database.PayRollEntities())
            {
                var AdministrationCode = dbcontext
                                 .tblEmployeeDatas
                                 .Where(u => u.EmployeeCode == EmpCodeAsInt)
                                 .Select(u => u.AdministrationCode)
                                 .SingleOrDefault();

                txtAdministrationNo.Text = Convert.ToByte( AdministrationCode);
            }
        }
}
```

This is my model class:

```
public int EmployeeCode { get; set; }
public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
public Nullable<byte> GenderCode { get; set; }
public Nullable<byte> PranchCode { get; set; }
public Nullable<byte> RelationShipCode { get; set; }
public Nullable<byte> AdministrationCode { get; set; }
public Nullable<byte> DepartmentCode { get; set; }
public Nullable<short> JopCode { get; set; }
public Nullable<byte> JopLevelCode { get; set; }
```

Comment: To convert a number type to a string, use `.ToString()` ?

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: it's working Convert.ToString( AdministrationCode);
thank U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has conversion mismatch :

```
txtAdministrationNo.Text = Convert.ToByte( AdministrationCode);
```

txtAdministrationNo.Text is string property and you must convert AdministrationCode to string.